# Constantly Connecting/Disconnecting with socket connection using node cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, cluster-computing

I am using node 4.2 and need to build server that would be connected to a client via socket.
Since the application is not a web, my socket connection is breaking and re-connecting continuously.

*But please look below for the server code:*

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var clusterWorkerSize = require('os').cpus().length;
var sticky = require('sticky-session');

var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
res.end('worker: ' + cluster.worker.id);
});

if (!sticky.listen(server, 14001)) {
console.log('master');
server.once('listening', function() {

console.log('server started on 14001 port');

});

} else {

console.log('worker: ' + cluster.worker.id);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    var userID = socket.id;
    console.log("connected "+userID);

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {

        console.log('Got disconnect!'+userID);
    });

});

}
```

*But please look below for the client code:*

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var serverUrl = 'http://localhost:14001';
var conn = io.connect(serverUrl);

conn.on('connect', function () {
var sessionId = conn.io.engine.id;
console.log(sessionId);

});
```

Please guide me if i am doing something wrong.
NOTE: I am initializing the socket io in worker.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not a web app", and how should it affect sockets?

Comment: "not a web app" means the mobile app would be in connection with node server using socket.io.

But i am trying to emulate this using node package "socket.io-client".

But my test run keeps on showing constant handshake failure and re-connection.

Comment: Anybody!! Any Help!! I am stuck here.

Comment: I am not sure the problem come from the fact it is not a "web app", I ve successfully used socket.io between multiple node.js server without thoses problems. Are you sure the network is stable? And does the constant disconnection/reconnection affect you a lot and prevent your app from working at all, or is it just something that worry you?

Comment: Thanks @DrakaSAN for the response. yes it does effect my functionality, i need the consistent/sticky session because there is long polling between app and node server using socket.io.

Actually, i am using node cluster mode to make worker work on all cpu cores on  a single machine, not with multiple node.js server.

Can you please help me for any demo example code for this cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server {transports: [ 'websocket', 'polling' ] });
```

Client side:

```
var conn = io.connect(serverUrl {transports: [ 'websocket', 'polling' ] });
```

If you are using Android Client:

```
IO.Options opt = new IO.Options();    
String[] trspt = {"websocket", "polling"};
opt.transports = trspt;
conn = IO.socket(serverUrl, opt);
```

Font: https://medium.com/@codeandcam/clustering-an-express-socket-io-server-with-pm2-789d11865f95